# Draw specified set on a complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Draw specified set on a complex plane:

$\left| z+\left(  \frac{1-i \sqrt{3} }{ \sqrt{2} + i \sqrt{2}  } \right) ^{36}  \right|  \ge \left| z+i\right|$

I am not sure how to do this, tried to calculate trigonometric form of expression in bracket, but failed.
Sorry for any spelling mistakes I made, English is not my primary language.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}} = \frac{e^{-i\pi/3}}{e^{i\pi/4}} = e^{-i7\pi/12}$ elevate that to the power 36 and you get $|z+e^{-i\pi}|\geq|z+i|$

So $|z-1|\geq|z+i|$

Interpret in terms of distance between $z$ to $1$ and $-i$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Hint $\frac{1-i\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2 +i\sqrt 2}=\frac{e^{i5\pi/6}}{e^{i\pi/4}}$

Answer (score 0):

in a first step prove that $$\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}}\right)^{30}=i$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

This is the same as 
$$\biggl|z+\Bigl(\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}{12}}\Bigr)^{36}\biggr|=\biggl|z-1\biggr|\ge |z+i|. $$
Interpret in terms of distance of $z$ to $1$ and $i$ respectively: this describes the half-plane *above* the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining the images of $i=e^{\tfrac{i\pi}{2}}$ and $1$; i.e. the line with (complex) equation: $\;\arg z=\frac{\pi}{4}$.